# Output different in C, PHP, java

Tags: java, php, c

I was struggling on one statement. When I execute this (similar) in C and PHP, I get answer as 5. But same code yields 4 in Java. Can somebody explain this difference.

```
int x=1,y=1;
x+=y+=x+=y;
```

We are concerned about the value of x after this execution.

Comment: Anything is correct in C because this invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Parse error in PHP.

Comment: Offcourse, it will as there isn't $ sign added. But i have this running with me with output 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the behavior of the expression `x+=y+=x+=y` is *undefined*; literally any result is possible.  The problem is that, with few exceptions, C does not specify the order in which expressions are evaluated or side effects are applied; there's no guarantee that `x` or `y` are updated in any specific order (the `+=` operator does not introduce a sequence point).  So, the result will vary between platforms, builds, etc.  It doesn't even have to be the same from run to run, although in practice it will be.

Yes, the expression *parses* as `x+=(y+=(x+=y))`, but that doesn't mean that the value of `x` is updated *immediately* after the rightmost `x+=y` is evaluated.

Here's one *possible* sequence of evaluations and side effects that can explain the output:

```
t0 <- x + y  // t0 == 2
t1 <- y + t0 // t1 == 3
 y <- t1     //  y == 3
 x <- t0     //  x == 2
 x <- x + t1 //  x == 5
```

Unlike C, Java forces a specific order of evaluation and side effects (everything is evaluated left to right, side effects are applied immediately), so the result is well-defined in Java.

Not a clue about PHP.